# Al hacer una consulta en una app móvil, esta se cierra

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo una app de consultas, pero al momento de intentar hacer una consulta o búsqueda, la app se cierra.
Esta es mi clase de `java` para la `base de datos` y no me marca error alguno:

```
public class AdministradorBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public AdministradorBase(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
    BaseDeDatos.execSQL("create table inventario(serie text primary key, ubicacion text, usuario text, ip int, datos text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
```

> Igual aqui, el programa no me marca nada, asi que no se que puedo identifica el error para solucionar este problema.

//metodo para consultar

```
public void Buscar(View view){
    AdministradorBase admin = new AdministradorBase(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String serie = et_serie.getText().toString();

    if (!serie.isEmpty()){
        Cursor fila = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select ubicación, usuario, ip, datos from inventario where serie =" + serie, null);


        if (fila.moveToFirst()){

            et_ubicacion.setText(fila.getString(0));
            et_usuario.setText(fila.getString(1));
            et_ip.setText(fila.getString(2));
            et_datos.setText(fila.getString(3));
            BaseDeDatos.close();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "El equipo no existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BaseDeDatos.close();
        }

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes escribir el numero de serie", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones un `try/catch` al momento de ejecutar tu método? `try { buscar(v) } catch(Exception ex) {Log.d("TAG", "error: " + e.getMessage()); }` de esta manera, en el `LogCat` podrás ver el error porque así como nos muestras no podemos saber el motivo de cierre de tu app.

Comment: hola, en el LogCat me parece lo siguiente cuando intento hacer la consulta/busqueda.                                                                                       
> aqui empieza el error 2022-03-24 19:13:39.807 1414-1414/com.example.issste E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ubicación in "select ubicación, usuario, ip, datos from inventario where serie =e"

Comment: Bueno, el error como se indica es que no encuentra la columna `ubicación`. ¿Has probado escribiendo `ubicación` pero sin la tilde?

Comment: >lo intenté pero sigue igual y me di cuenta que me sale esto, cada vez que se corre el programa  **2022-03-27 13:33:38.125 9908-9932/com.example.issste E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory**

Comment: ¿Has probado con reinstalar? ¿Por qué aquí dice: `super(context, name, factory, version);` y no esto `super(context, "administracion", factory, 1);`?

Comment: 2022-04-30 21:52:01.585 23632-23662/com.example.equipos E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory´    siempre me sale esa advertencia cada vez que inicia el equipo,

Answer (score 0):

Sé que la respuesta es muy tarde, y soy malo explicando, pero lo siguiente debería funcionar:

En tu método Buscar, cambia `"administracion"` por `"BaseDeDatos"`

También cambia :

```
SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos
```

a:

```
SQLiteDataBase administracion
```

Comment: `soy malo explicando`, esta limitación se tira abajo con una estrategia simple: intenta colocar los elementos sobre la mesa, cuando sientas que están todos en la mesa, intenta ordenarlos según lo que creas conveniente, ¿Te equivocaste de orden? No pasa nada, ya intentaste una ruta, tienes la chance de intentar otra ruta, ¿Te volviste a equivocar de orden? No pasa nada, ya adquiriste 2 rutas erróneas (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) mantienes este algoritmo en el C:\erebro hasta que sientas por dónde ir con fluidez, una vez ahí, guarda esa ruta en el C:\orazón, esto te aumenta la intuición y como previamente tienes la lógica instalada en el C:\erebro. Vas a poder explicar de buena manera. Ánimos y sin miedo al error, los valientes aprenden de ellos con mayor velocidad :D Ah y por cierto, agrega los detalles en la respuesta antes que te den negativos por baja calidad. Saludos.